# What is the first moment area of a rounded rectangle?

Tags: civil-engineering, mathematics

I need to calculate the plastic section modulus of a rectangular section with rounded corners. First I need to know the formula for first moment area of a quadrant. I can't find it anywhere on the internet. Does anyone know?

Comment: By quadrant, do you mean 1/4 of a circle?

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma, yes, that is the definition of a quadrant. I am not sure what is unclear about this straight forward question. Perhaps Wasabi et all can explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a simple formula but that is the way i would handle it. Assuming the four corners are circular with equal radius r, so that symmetry exists, the first moment of area of **one half** of the section should be:

$$S_{half} = S_{half\,rect}-2S_{corner}$$

where

- $S_{half\,rect} = b(h/2)(h/4) = \frac{bh^2}{8} $ the 1st moment of
  area of the half rectangle (with intact corners) around neutral axis and
- $S_{corner}$ the 1st moment of area of the removed material from each
  corner, around neutral axis.

  [image: basic shape]

### How to find $S_{corner}$

We have to find its area and the distance of its centroid from the section neutral axis. It helps to consider the removed corner as a quarter circle subtracted from an r x r square (see figure below). The area is then simply found, by subtracting form the small r x r square, a circular quarter (see figure below):
$$A_{corner} = r^2 - \frac{πr^2}{4} $$

[image: detail of the removed corner]

The centroid of the removed corner area, relative to the top edge, is similarly found  considering the centroid of the rxr square (red dot) which is located $y=r/2$ below top edge and the centroid of the quarter circle (blue dot) which is located $y=r-\frac{4r}{3\pi}$ from the top edge. Combining them both, we get the distance of centroid of the removed corner from the top edge:

$$ y_{corner} = \frac{1}{A_{corner}}\left(r^2\cdot\frac{r}{2} - \frac{\pi r^2}{4} \left(r-\frac{4r}{3\pi}\right)\right) $$

Having found the above, the first moment of area of one removed corner around the section neutral axis is:
$$ S_{corner} = A_{corner}\left(\frac{h}{2} - y_{corner}\right)$$

### Finally

Substituting $ S_{corner}$ to the 1st formula, we get the 1st moment of area of the half section $S_{half}$. Then, the plastic modulus of the total section, taking advantage of symmmetry, is:

$$Z=2S_{half}$$

For verification of the result [a rounded rectangle calculator](http://calcresource.com/cross-section-rectround.html) may prove handy.

Comment: First moment area of the removed corner is just area times moment arm? How about rotation about its own axis?

Comment: By definition,1st moment of area is sum of area times distance from axis. Remember that we are talking of the first moment of area not the second.